# Find multiple word-patterns in files

Tags: grep, find

I have around 50000 files (.txt) and more items in filesdir folder.The values: 'fax', 'phone', 'address' are presented in different configurations in these files.
I need to find all files which contain 'fax' AND 'phone' and does not contain 'address'.
I tried for loop with a few grep commands. ls gives 'too many arguments'. 
So I tried:

```
find /filesdir/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec grep -l 'fax' \; grep -l 'phone' \; grep -l -v 'address'
```

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons that would not work:

- you have omitted the `{}` placeholder for the `-exec`
- you are trying to `-exec` multiple `grep` commands with a single invocation
- I suspect your logic is flawed since the default operation for find is logical `AND` whereas you presumably want `fax` OR `phone` AND `not address`

I haven't fully tested it but I think you want something more like

```
find /filesdir/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec grep -q 'fax\|phone' {} \; -exec grep -lv 'address' {} \;
```

Comment: I'm sorry for opening it again. I want now to restrict the results to 10 first. Using | head at the end of the command. I' getting: "grep' terminated by signal 13". The question is: how to get rid of it.

Comment: you need to use `-L` option instead of  `-lv` in `grep -lv 'address' `, since you will get false positive result for the file containing `phone address\nfax`. In addition OP wants `'fax' AND 'phone' and does not contain 'address'` while you are stated _"fax OR phone AND not address"_  and looking either a `fax` or `phone` `not address`

Answer (score 2):

#### [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

You can use `git grep` for multiple patterns combined using Boolean expressions, e.g.:

```
git grep --all-match --no-index -e "fax" --and -e "phone" --and --not -e "address"
```

<sup>You can combine different patterns with *Boolean* expressions such as `--and`, `--or` and `--not`.</sup>

> `--all-match` When giving multiple pattern expressions, this flag is specified to **limit the match to files that have lines to match all of them**.
>
> `--no-index` **Search files in the current directory that is not managed by Git.**
>
> `-l`/`--files-with-matches`/`--name-only` Show only the names of files.
>
> `-e` The next parameter is the pattern. Default is to use basic regexp.

Other params to consider:

> `--threads` Number of grep worker threads to use.
>
> `-q`/`--quiet`/`--silent` Do not output matched lines; exit with status 0 when there is a match.

To change the pattern type, you may also use `-G`/`--basic-regexp` (default), `-F`/`--fixed-strings`, `-E`/`--extended-regexp`, `-P`/`--perl-regexp`, `-f file`, and other.

Check `man git-grep` for further help.

#### `grep`

Here is the `grep` syntax which uses chain of [command substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution):

```
grep -L "address" $(grep -l "phone" $(grep -rl "fax" .))
```

Explanation:

1. Find the filenames having the "fax" pattern (`grep -rl "fax" .`).
2. Filter found filenames which are having "phone" pattern (`grep -l "phone" $(cmd)`).
3. Filter further down to exclude files not having `address` (`grep -L "address" $(cmd)`).

If you're working with large data, consider using [`ripgrep`](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/) instead.

#### `find`

Above example may not work well with files with whitespaces, so here is the version with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' \
  -execdir bash -c 'grep -L "address" "$(grep -l "phone" "$(grep -l "fax" "{}")")"' ';' \
2>/dev/null
```

---

See also: [Check if all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762772/55075)

Comment: I'm sorry for opening it again. I want now to restrict the results to 10 first. Using | head at the end of the command. I' getting: "grep' terminated by signal 13". The question is: how to get rid of it.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk Can you try a `git grep`, I think it's a better, quicker tool, no need for multiple pipes. I've added info how to use it without git repo.

Comment: Your `find` solution is still doesn't work for the files including whitespace. As well as your `git grep` solution doesn't list a file containing the patterns in multiple lines like `fax\nphone`

Answer (score 1):

### Printing the file names and their content on one line for each file

I think this command line will do it:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec echo "{} :" \; -exec cat {} \; -exec echo EOF \;| tr '\n' ' '|sed 's/EOF /\n/g'|grep -iv 'address'|grep -i 'fax'|grep -i 'phone'
```

Explanation:

- for each file (which is found by `find`)

  - echo the file name
  - print the content
  - print an End Of File flag (that should be different from what can be inside the files. Select this flag carefully! I use EOF, you may need something else.
- for the whole output

  - convert the newlines to spaces to get everything on one line
  - convert the End Of File flags to newlines

  Now the content of each file is in one separate line, suitable for `grep` .
- and finally

  - skip lines with 'address'
  - from the remaining output, select lines with 'fax'
  - from the remaining output, select lines with 'phone'

### Printing only the file names

The previous command line prints the file names and the file content (merged to one line), which is good for testing, but not for processing thousands of files.

The following command line prints only the file names. It uses ':::' to  separate each file name from the content of the file.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec echo "{} :::" \; -exec cat {} \; -exec echo EOF \;| tr '\n' ' '|sed 's/EOF /\n/g'|grep -iv 'address'|grep -i 'fax'|grep -i 'phone' | sed 's/ :::.*//'
```

Comment: Tnx. Will it give phone AND fax?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk, Try it with a few real files :-) I have tested it with some test files, and it works for me. The current version prints the content of the files, which you may not want, but I am working on a version, which writes only the file names (of the files that contain 'phone' and 'fax' but not 'address'.

Comment: Had run it. Works. Tnx.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk, You are welcome. I enjoyed doing it :-)

Comment: I'm sorry for opening it again. I want now to restrict the results to 10 first. Using | head at the end of the command. I' getting: "grep' terminated by signal 13". The question is: how to get rid of it.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk,  Are you getting correct output too, or only the message "grep' terminated by signal 13"? And are you getting it at the end of the output, once somewhere else, or several times?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I'm getting correct output: first 10 occurrence, and after that - grep terminated etc. So I must press ctrl+c  to get rid of it every time.

Comment: @JosefKlimuk, I did some testing, but I did not get that problem. Please supply a set of files, that can be used to get that problem, and I can test it.

Comment: Oo. I'm sorry - your solution works normally, I got this problem using the steeldriver's one...

Comment: @JosefKlimuk, I'm glad that my command line works like it should also for you, when piped through `head` :-)

Answer (score 1):

To find files ( compatible with files including whitespace/or newline ) those doesn't contain the pattern `address`:

```
find -type f ! -exec grep -q 'address' {} \; -print
```

and print only those that contains the patterns `fax` ***and*** `phone` in any order in whole file:

```
find -type f ! -exec grep -q 'address' {} \; \
               -exec grep -qP '(?s)(?=.*?fax)(?=.*?phone)' {} \; -print
```

Or POSIXly:

```
find -type f ! -exec grep -q 'address' {} \; \
               -exec grep -q 'fax' {} \; \
               -exec grep -q 'phone' {} \; -print
```

Or assuming there is no `\n`ewline in files name, then:

```
grep -lP '(?s)(?=.*?fax)(?=.*?phone)' * |xargs -d'\n' grep -L address
```

- `(?=pattern)`: Positive Lookahead: The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.
- `(?s)` Known "dot-all" which tells *grep* to allow the dot `.` to match `\n`ewline characters as well.
- The `.*?` means matching any characters `.` that occurrences zero or more times `*` while they are optional followed by a pattern(`fax` or `phone`). The `?` makes everything optional before it (means zero or one time of everything matched `.*`)

future reading:

[Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2973436/4023950)